# Passing Variable in Shell to Teradata BTEQ

Tags: bash, shell, unix, teradata

I am new to Unix and Terdata BTEQ. I want to pass variables to the .sh file which calls the .sql file which has the SQL code. 
Before doing that, I am trying to atleast define the parameter value in the .sh file and having the SQL code within the .sh file itself. However it does not seem to work,

Following is the code i am trying,

```
     temp_table=`PRP_D1_WORK.ADHOC_CMSC_NIEL_BRND_DICT_STG`

    .LOGON tddev/username,Pass

    .SET WIDTH 1500 ;
    .set heading '';

    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $temp_table;

    .LOGOFF
    .EXIT
```

Now i run this statement in Unix (Via putty) using the command:

```
bteq < sample.sh
```

The error that I get here is $temp_table does not exist, which i think means is that the variable is not getting passed.

Once I m able to achieve this, I want to pass the variable value while executing the shell script as well or by defining the HERE doc.

Let me know what is the error in this case.

Thanks,
Priyash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes sure, you can pass arguments to the shell script as

```
sample.sh temp_table_name login_id
```

Inside the script you need to use $1, $2 ...so on where $1 is the first argument, $2 is the second argument etc..
Here temp_table is temp_table_name that you have passed as the first argument and $2=login_id

```
 temp_table=$1

.LOGON $2/username,Pass

.SET WIDTH 1500 ;
.set heading '';

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $temp_table;

.LOGOFF
.EXIT
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I was able to solve it.
I should have included bteq in the .sh file

and just run the .sh instead of bteq < sample.sh

and it worked.

Moving to the next question, can i pass the parameters defined at the top of the .sh file to the .sql file which i will call inside the .sh
using 
.run example.sql

Comment: commenting and asking questions in an answer will not lead anywhere